# Using #define to create styles

Tags: objective-c, syntax, coding-style, c-preprocessor

I am wondering if I can use a series of `#DEFINE` to create style options for my app.

For example,

```
#DEFINE style1: backGroundColor = [UIColor: colorNamed whiteColor];
txtColor = [UIColor blackColor];  #DEFINE style2....
```

My question is: What is the syntax for this statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is certainly possible to use `DEFINE` statements to create style options for your app, I'm wondering if the use of preprocessor directives makes sense for functionality such as styles, which are going to be collections to properties.  If you use `DEFINE` statements to define your styles, it makes it difficult to ultimately provide style selection as a run-time option to your users.

Instead, I tend to think you will be better off creating a class hierarchy for this, and implementing it as a singleton.  With a class hierarchy, you can define any general style behaviors in your root class, and then inherit from that to implement specific styles.  Later on, you can expose the ability to select styles to your user if you want.

Comment: Thanks Rob. That sounds robust. I will look for code samples that are similar.

Comment: I thing the best would be use a singleton and define the colors and everything into a xml (plist) file. If you want the user to change style during runtime, you can't use preprocessor. If you want different application versions with different styles, I recommend preprocessor.

Comment: I think this is the best solution for me, as I want people to be able to change settings at runtime. I've created the xml file, so I just need to parse it, and I'm done. Thanks a ton to all of you.. I wish I could mark you all as having solved my question. I have up-marked you all. David

Answer (score 1):

`#define backgroundColor [UIColor whiteColor]` then to use it you would say `UIColor *txtColor = backgroundColor;`.

Although you may only be able to use `whiteColor` as the definition instead of `[UIColor whiteColor]`. You would then call `[UIColor backgroundColor];` instead of the above example.

I would not do this to generate stylings. Defining various settings outside of code would be a good idea but using defines is pretty binding and defeats the purpose of de-coupling the UI from code.

---

In a `#define` do not put a semicolon anywhere. When the preprocessor inserts the definition it will insert whatever semicolon is there exactly as it is; **you do not want the preprocessor inserting semicolons.** When writing the definition you probably don't know all the places you'll write it, therefore you shouldn't have a semicolon in it because you may write it inline an expression.

Another option is to use `const` instead.

In code I've written I have `#define`s for string literals `@"literal string"` and numbers. In other places I use the `const` declaration which looks like this:

```
//static type *const variableName = assignment;

static NSString *const kConstantString = @"Constant variable";
```

Constants don't use the preprocessor to fill in the information. If you access a define frequently and it uses some computation it might may be better suited to a constant declaration which is stored only once.

The other big reason I used `const` instead of `#define` is that define is not type-checked as it's handled by the preprocessor. Define basically turns off the compiler warnings and only gives you errors; strict warnings are extremely helpful and can save a lot of frustration.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I tried using a const  like this: static NSString *const kBlack = @"[UIColor: colorNamed blackColor]"; but I get an warning of incompatible pointer types..

Comment: You're putting a method call inside a string. That won't do.

Comment: This will work: `#define defColor [UIColor redColor]` then `self.view.backgroundColor = defColor;`

Comment: Thanks Joe, but what if I want several statements - text info, color info, etc. I guess I'm looking for some macro function..

Comment: What do you mean? Like writing multiple lines of code in defines? That sounds difficult to me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this syntax:

Setting a style

```
#define STYLE1
//#define STYLE2
```

and then anywhere in your code (class level or method level, header or implementation file).

```
#ifdef STYLE1
   //code for the first style
   UIColor* backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
#elif STYLE2
   //code for the second style
   UIColor* backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
#else
   //code for the third style
   UIColor* backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
#endif
```

More about C preprocessor: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Comment: thanks Sulthan, what would the code look like for "Style1"? Is it simply whatever I put into curly brackets?

Comment: There can be completely anything. During compilation, only one block is compiled and the others are not there. I'll put an example.